# Rails check if expiration date is 1 year from today

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm trying but date format is not correct, I'm also doing it in a controller

Date format of `expiration_date` in database is `2025-01-15 08:00:00`.

```rb
if @car_subscription.expiration_date.present?  && @car_subscription.expiration_date == @car_subscription.expiration_date == Date.today + 1.year 
   @car_subscription.update(new_cars: @car_subscription.new_cars = 20)
end
```

Comment: From the post, it appears that the database is returning a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` and the Ruby code is attempting to compare this with a `Date` using implicit type casts. There are many ways that this can go wrong. Use explicit type casts and ensure that time zone concerns are addressed.

Comment: `Date.today.to_datetime #=> 2024-01-15T00:00:00+00:00` and `DateTime.new(2024,01,15,8) #=> 2024-01-15T08:00:00+00:00`. As you can see the today's date when compared with a Date Time will never be equal because the timestamp for a bare date is always "12:00 AM" or "00:00:00"

Comment: _"date format is not correct"_ – what's not correct about the date format? Be specific.

Comment: BTW, having an assignment (`@car_subscription.new_cars = 20`) inside the `update` call looks like a bug. You either assign a value to an attribute and call `save` or you pass the new value to an `update` call, but not both.

Comment: The second part of your condition seems to be incorrect: `@car_subscription.expiration_date == @car_subscription.expiration_date == Date.today + 1.year`. Why the duplicated `@car_subscription.expiration_date ==`? What do you try to achieve with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare a DateTime instance (`@car_subscription.expiration_date`) and a Date instance (`Date.today + 1.year`). Actually, technically it's not an incorrect comparison.

But if we assume that `expiration_date` field is a timestamp that is created depending on creation of the record (it may have very different hour/minute/second values) and return value of `Date.today + 1.year` value will refer first second of that day, the probability of equality here will be very low.

If you want to check if `expiration_date` is equal to one year from today, casting this field as date object would be healthier for comparison.

So you can try something like this:

```rb
if @car_subscription.expiration_date.present?  && @car_subscription.expiration_date.to_date == Date.today + 1.year 
  @car_subscription.update(new_cars: @car_subscription.new_cars = 20)
end
```

By the way, in your snippet, you wrote below statement twice `@car_subscription.expiration_date`. I assume this as a typo.

Thanks to @Stefan for correction.

Comment: _"it's impossible to be evaluated as true"_ – `DateTime.new(2023,1,16) == Date.new(2023,1,16)` is `true`.

Comment: Yes, you are actually right, but assuming that the expiration_date (I thought this field would be created depending on the creation of the record and would have very different hour/minute/second values) field is a timestamp, the (Date.today+1.year) field will not be equal because it will refer to the first second of the day. I wanted to say that the possibility is very difficult. But yes, it is technically possible. That's why I thought it would be healthier to make a day-based comparison and suggested it that way. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Burak, SO will no doubt inform Stefan that your comment has been left for him--as his is the only earlier comment--but in general you should include "@Stefan" in your comment to ensure that that he is notified. That is not necessary for comments left on questions and answers that are directed to their authors.

Comment: @BurakErsoy you should incorporate that explanation into your answer (and maybe edit the “it’s impossible” part)

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks for informing, I will learn more about posts/comments